# how to add an image to product in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i have a pragmatically added product in my code , the product is added to presta correctly but not about its image .

here is some part of my code that i used :

```
                    $url=  "localhost\prestashop\admin7988\Hydrangeas.jpg" ;
                $id_productt = $object->id;         
                $shops = Shop::getShops(true, null, true);    
                $image = new Image();
                $image->id_product = $id_productt ;
                $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($id_productt) + 1 ;
                $image->cover = true; // or false;echo($godyes[$dt][0]['image']);
                if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
                    ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add())
                    {
                        $image->associateTo($shops);
                        if (! self::copyImg($id_productt, $image->id, $url, 'products', false))
                            {
                            $image->delete();
                        }
                    }
```

but my product have not any image yet

the problem is in copyImg method ...

here is my copyImg function :

```
         function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url, $entity = 'products')
{
    $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
    $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));

    switch ($entity)
    {
        default:
        case 'products':
            $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
            $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
        break;
        case 'categories':
            $path = _PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_.(int)$id_entity;
        break;
    }
    $url = str_replace(' ' , '%20', trim($url));
    // Evaluate the memory required to resize the image: if it's too much, you can't resize it.
    if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($url))
        return false;
    // 'file_exists' doesn't work on distant file, and getimagesize make the import slower.
    // Just hide the warning, the traitment will be the same.
    if (@copy($url, $tmpfile))
    {
        ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'.jpg');
        $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity);
        foreach ($images_types as $image_type)
            ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'-'.stripslashes($image_type['name']).'.jpg', $image_type['width'],
             $image_type['height']);

        if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types))
            Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity));
    }
    else
    {
        unlink($tmpfile);
        return false;
    }
    unlink($tmpfile);
    return true;
}
```

can anybody help me ?

Comment: note that here is the corrupted url that the products get : http://localhost/prestashop/24-large_default/-.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. You are passing 5th parameter (with value) to copyImg, while the function does not have such.
2. Your foreach ($images_types as $image_type) loop must include the Hook as well (add open/close curly braces).

   ```
   foreach ($images_types as $image_type) 
   { 
       ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path.'-'.stripslashes($image_type['name']).'.jpg', $image_type['width'], $image_type['height']); 

       if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types)) 
           Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity)); 
   }
   ```

You should also check if the product is imported correctly, expecially the "link_rewrite" and if the image is phisically uploaded in the /img/ folder.

Comment: tnx alot dear PrestaShop-Developer.c for replying

Comment: i was a stupid ! i solved my problem and the wrong thing was a silly mistake that confused me for a week ! it was in URL , i changes is to "http: //localhost/prestashop/admin7988/Hydrangeas.jpg" and my problem being solved .

Comment: any way , i give a green tick to your answer because of two thing : 1 . your pleasure , 2 . your right answer to the code